# Python Numpy Error

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am following this tutorial to use numpy with rospy

http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy

when I am running

> rosrun numpy_tutorial
> numpy_listener.py

I am getting the following error

> terminate called after throwing an
> instance of 'rospack::Exception'
> what():  error parsing manifest of
> package numpy_tutorial at
> /home/tanmay/catkin_ws/numpy_tutorial/package.xml

any suggestions what I might be doing incorrectly?

Thanks,
TM

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138656/python-numpy-error/) by [nicobari](https://answers.ros.org/users/4293/nicobari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [s1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21751/s1/) on 2015-09-22**:
Im getting an error: [rospack] Error: package 'numpy_tutorial' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure what the exact problem is, but the error is pretty clear -- package.xml in numpy_tutorial is unparseable. Perhaps post the contents of that file and we can debug what is actually wrong with it.

(as for why you're even parsing package.xml, you've made a call to roslib.load_manifest().. it should be noted, that this is not needed for an actual catkin package, and in fact, is generally recommended not to do with a catkin package. You might try removing that line also. Regardless, I'd guess that tutorial is out of date)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nicobari](https://answers.ros.org/users/4293/nicobari/) on 2014-03-11**:
eah it is working after I removed the line thank you.